# IntelliJ IDEA constantly reindexing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reindex

I am working on a very large project in IntelliJ IDEA (currently version Ultimate 2020.1.4) - with over 100,000 java files, close to 50,000 resource files, dozens of modules, several gigabytes of external libraries - you get the idea.

When I first opened the project, it took a good 30 minutes or so for IntelliJ to index the project (which I did expect).  However now, as I work with the project, almost constantly IDEA shows message "Search for files to reindex" and "Reindexing" - the reindexing is running almost all the time. This makes development and especially debugging a *very* painful experience indeed.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling IntelliJ; deleting the entire source tree and re-cloning the git repo - the behaviour is still there.

Any suggestions on how I can get it to stop constantly search for files to reindex?

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate the caches using the menu option File > Invalidate Caches / Restart?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, that was the first thing I tried.  Then waited for about 30 minutes for the initial index to be rebuilt

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. Please try [2020.2 release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

If the issue persists, [report it in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Add the following in Help | Diagnostic Tools | Debug Log Settings:

```
#com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl:trace
```